# List<Object> is return size = 30 when it only has one object in it Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have some mapping that saves a `List<Entrants>` in an `Event` entity, each time a new `Entrants` to an `Event` is saved, I add the `Entrant` to the `List<Entrants>` but when I get the `List<Entrants>` it says that size = 30 even if I only have one `Entrants` object there. It always seems to add 30 so if I save 4 `Entrants` it would then say it is 120.

When saving a new `Entrants`,

```java
public void save(String event, long memberId) {
    Event e = eventRepo.findEventByName(event);
    Member m = memberRepo.getOne(memberId);
    Entrants en = new Entrants(m, e, 0, 0);
    //Update the current entrants entered in an event by 1
    e.setCurrentEntrants(e.getCurrentEntrants() + 1);
    eventRepo.save(e);
    //Get the current list of entrants for this event
    List<Entrants> entrants = e.getEntrants();
    //Add the current entrant to the list of entrants for this event.
    entrants.add(en);
    entrantsRepo.save(en);
}
```

After running this code to add a new `Entrant` it works fine and after calling `entrants.add(en)` the `List<Entrants> entrants` size is 1 as expected.

When I then call `getEntrants()` (Note I want to return a List hence the return type)

```java
public List<Member> getEntrants(String eventName){
    Event event = eventRepo.findEventByName(eventName);
    List<Entrants> entrants = event.getEntrants();
    List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Entrants entrant: entrants) {
        members.add(entrant.getMember());
    }
    System.out.println(entrants.size());
    return members;
}
```

It says that the `List is 30! and it shows 30 Entrants all exactly the same. If I save 4 different entrants, then it shows 30 of the first entrant, then 30 of the next etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my mapping in the `Event` entity solved this. I changed fetch from `EAGER` to `LAZY` I can't find anything to explain why `EAGER` would return 30 of each `Entrants` object though.

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //Was previously EAGER
    private List<Entrants> entrants;
```